# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

How to compute integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx$? I try to change it to polar coordinates but I have only one variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Square and change to polar coordinates. Very common integral.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates) ...

Comment: I thought the univariate normal pdf had no closed form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern no antiderivative needed, when you alter to polar coordinates, you can integrate over "nice" regions like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^+$...

Comment: $\int_{R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=1$ can you get if from here?

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate, but I can't find one.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern with these bounds it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral in question and note that
$$
I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy
=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}r^2}r\,dr\,d\theta
$$
by changing to polar coordinates. The last integral is easy to compute.